# PHP If else statement that a database record is empty it will display a default picture

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Hi basicly I am trying to create a simple IF statement that shows a default picture if one hasn't been entered in to my database. I am using server to store my picture and a database to store the file name, so I can get the image to display if it has a file name in the db but I want the If statement to say if the record is empty display this default image. I have some code here that I have tried however it doesn't work any thoughts? I tried a few other ways of doing it but they didn't work either.

Cheers.

Code so far:

```
//Retrieves data from MySQL
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db*****") or die(mysql_error());

//Puts it into an array
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
?>

        <div class="member">
        <div class="imageSection">
       <? 

        if($info['photo'] == '')
         {echo "<img class=\"memberImage\" src=images/default.jpg>";}
          else {echo "<img class=\"memberImage\" src=images/".$info['photo'] .">";}
         ?>
        </div>  
        <div class="memberInfo">
<? Echo "<p><strong>Name: ".$info['nameMember'] . "</strong></p>";
Echo "<p>Position: ".$info['bandMember'] . " </p>";
Echo "<p>About Band Member ".$info['nameMember'] .":".$info['aboutMember'] . "</p>";
Echo "<p>Other Bands: ".$info['otherBands'] . " </p><br/></div></div><br class=\"clearBoth\"/>";

}
?>
```

Comment: What part isn't working?  Looks like you'd want quotes around your img src attribute e.g. src="filename" but other than that it looks okay.

Comment: Have you tried to print_r($info) to see if the value is in fact '' and not something else?

Answer (score 4):

What about a simple [ternary](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison):

```
$photo = ($info['photo'] == null) ? "default.jpg" : $info['photo'];
echo "<img class=\"memberImage\" src=images/". $photo .">";
```

Comment: I tired that but it hasn't displayed the default picture. It displays the uploaded pictures, this is the same problem I had with the code I put up above. Thanks though, did you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the default value for the column is set to "". it could be set to null?  although idk if that would cause it not work.

add the following code before the if statement

```
echo $info['photo'];
```

Another suggestion would be to trim the data before comparing it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [file_exists](http://php.net/function.file-exists), which will work even if the image is deleted manually.

```
$photo = 'images/'. $info['photo'];
if (file_exists($photo) == FALSE)
{
  $photo = 'images/default.jpg';
} 
echo '<img class="memberImage" src="'. $photo .'"/>';
```

Comment: +1 Good call. I would do it this way regardless of any database issues.

Answer (score 0):

[empty()](http://php.net/empty) can catch the sort of conditions you are after, so try

```
 if(empty($info['photo']))
 {
     ....
 }
```

empty() returns true if the parameter is '', NULL, false, '0', 0, or an empty array.