# How can i display the default image?

Tags: php, css

I am trying to get the default image if no image is uploaded by the user but I get always the image which is uploaded by the user and the default does not show up.

Here is SQL query code and CSS part.

```
$query="INSERT INTO tbl_images (f_naam) VALUES ('$filename')";
if($result=mysql_query($query) or die ('query fout') ){
?>
<img src="data/<?php echo $filename; ?>"  width="220" />
<?php }else{ ?>
        <img src="http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/12716227/2/istockphoto_12716227-close-up-of-a-cute-young-couple-smiling-togetherjpg" width="220" />
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: you already said that **if** user does not upload any image **then** show the default and also writing that user is uploading an image; then obvioulsy that image would be display. where is the problem??

Comment: if no image is uploaded by the user then the second part after }else{ should be displayed but it does not show up the image out of www

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure if this is the problem BUT i suspect that even if `$filename` is empty, the query would run successfully and you would go into the section trying to display the uploaded image. So you might want to put a check on `$filename` and make sure it has something before running the query.

I might do it something like this, untested code though.

```
<?php 

    $picture_to_show = "http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/12716227/2/istockphoto_12716227-close-up-of-a-cute-young-couple-smiling-togetherjpg";

    if($filename){
        $query="INSERT INTO tbl_images (f_naam) VALUES ('$filename')";
        if($result=mysql_query($query) ){
            $picture_to_show = "data/".$filename;
        }
    }   

?>
<img src="<?php echo $picture_to_show; ?>"  width="220" />
```

Comment: this is what i really wanted but it shows only the default image(the one out of the url) the one out of DB does not show up. Could you help plz

Comment: heyyyyyyyyyyy Sabeen i got it right it is working thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

check if a picture is available in database (asuming that when no picture is uploaded the DB returns NULL)
if the test is true(!=NULL) show that picture
else (==NULL) show default

is the same question not already answered?
[PHP If else statement that a database record is empty it will display a default picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497194/php-if-else-statement-that-a-database-record-is-empty-it-will-display-a-default-p)

- thanks I now know how to search on this site. I searched on "default picture [php]"

the question got edited 14 seconds before i posted my answer - now it displays the actual code, before it did not

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the problem, but you are missing an opening quote here... after the `img src=`

`<img src=http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/12716227/2/istockphoto_12716227-close-up-of-a-cute-young-couple-smiling-togetherjpg" width="220" />`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an opening double-quote on the `src=` attribute for the default image:

```
<img src=http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/12716227/2/istockphoto_12716227-close-up-of-a-cute-young-couple-smiling-togetherjpg" width="220" />
    ----^^^----
```

Should be

```
<img src="http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/12716227/2/istockphoto_12716227-close-up-of-a-cute-young-couple-smiling-togetherjpg" width="220" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic needs some improvement. Unless your query is synactically wrong or the data violates the constraint, the mysql_query call will always return NON-false. If you want to handle a no-file-was-uploaded case, try this:

```
if ($_FILES['name_of_upload_field'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    ... insert into db ...
    ... display uploaded image...
} else {
    ... there was no upload, or upload failed
    ... display default image ...
}
```

Simply doing a blind insert and trying to check if it failed is NOT the way to go.

Assuming that `$filename` in your example is extracted from the $_FILES array, then your version will ALWAYS try to show the default image. Even if no file is uploaded, `$filename` will come out blank, and the insert query will be

```
INSERT INTO tbl_images (f_naam) VALUES ('')
```

which would alway succeed. `mysql_query()` will return a statement handle, which is NOT false, so the `if()` check succeeds, and you try to show the "uploaded" image.

Answer (score 1):

the line 2 --

```
if($result=mysql_query($query) or die ('query fout') )
```

seems strange to me. The condition is "either the query succeeds or we terminate the script" means that you won't get the `else`-part of this condition to fire - either the condition is satisfied or the script is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start saying that this 'answer' is not written to offend you, but the code you've written in your question is a bit of a mess. First of all, what are you inserting? You've never set $filename to any value and thus inserting makes no sence.

Second you're doing some sort of if-then-else-statement, using the MySQL insert statement. This insert statement is always going to return 'true', unless the database is unreachable or the query is wrong. This happens because a MySQL INSERT statement is only returning false if the insert fails. However even an empty insert (if $filename is empty) will succeed, thus showing the (maybe not available) photo the user tried to upload.

Third if the query is going wrong (MySQL injection or database unavailable) the die() statement will overtake in your case. For this reason you will NEVER be able to reach the 'else'-statement of your code - and thus never show the default image.

Last, there are some errors in the HTML part of your script. Make sure you fix those before you continue working on this script.

The correct code should look something like this:

```
<div class="filesize">JPG minimaal 800x60 pixels max. 2Mb</div>
<a href="" class="submit" title="Upload" name="upload"><span>Upload</span></a>
<div class="customerUploadPicture">

  <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `f_naam` FROM tbl_images WHERE `f_user` = 'ID'");
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if($data['f_name'] != '') {
  ?>
      <img src="data/<?php echo $data['f_naam']; ?>"  width="220" />
  <?php }else{ ?>
    <img src="DEFAULT PHOTO" width="220" />
  <?php } ?>

</div>
```

If you actually want to upload the photo, please check [this TiZag tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php).